# Can't mutate state directly, but using setState results in a null error

Tags: reactjs, components, state, setstate

I'm building a React 16.13 application.  I have this component ...

```
render() {
    const tags = this.props.values.map(result => (
        {
            id: result.name,
            text: result.name
        }));
    this.state = {
        tags: tags,
        suggestions: this.props.suggestions ? this.props.suggestions.map(result => ({
            id: result.name,
            text: result.name
        })) : []
    };

    return (
        <div className="form-group">
            <FormLabel>Coop Type(s)</FormLabel>
            <ReactTags tags={this.state.tags}
                suggestions={this.state.suggestions}
                handleDelete={this.handleDeletion}
                handleAddition={this.handleAddition}
                handleDrag={this.handleDrag}
                delimiters={delimiters} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

This produces the warning upon startup ...

```
Line 52:9:  Do not mutate state directly. Use setState()
```

So I tried changing to "setState," as recommended ...

```
render() {
    const tags = this.props.values.map(result => (
        {
            id: result.name,
            text: result.name
        }));
    this.setState({
        tags: tags,
        suggestions: this.props.suggestions ? this.props.suggestions.map(result => ({
            id: result.name,
            text: result.name
        })) : []
    }); 

    return (
        <div className="form-group">
            <FormLabel>Coop Type(s)</FormLabel>
            <ReactTags tags={this.state.tags}
                suggestions={this.state.suggestions}
                handleDelete={this.handleDeletion}
                handleAddition={this.handleAddition}
                handleDrag={this.handleDrag}
                delimiters={delimiters} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

but then this results in an error on startup ...

```
  60 | return (
  61 |     <div className="form-group">
  62 |         <FormLabel>Coop Type(s)</FormLabel>
> 63 |         <ReactTags tags={this.state.tags}
     | ^
  64 |             suggestions={this.state.suggestions}
  65 |             handleDelete={this.handleDeletion}
  66 |             handleAddition={this.handleAddition}
```

What is the proper way to set the state without getting this null error?

Comment: Are you trying to initialize state or update it? If you're trying to initialize it, just move the first example into the constructor. Then it is not mutation, but initialization, and is acceptable.

Comment: Both?  The "suggestions" prop is populated by an AJAX call from its parent component, so initially it is empty but after the AJAX call completes it has an array.

Answer (score 1):

You should not call `setState` inside the `render` function.

> The render() function should be pure, meaning that it does not modify
> component state, it returns the same result each time it’s invoked,
> and it does not directly interact with the browser.

[from the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render)

In this particular case what is happening is that you are tying to use `state.tags` but `setState` has not updated the state yet.

If you want to set the state based on the props you can set it directly in the [`constructor`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor) or use [`getDerivedStateFromProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your constructor if you want to initialise it. Constructor would be present at class level. If you want to update the stateon props change than you may use method: `getDerivedStateFromProps`. You can read about it

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops

```
constructor(props){
super(props);
let tags = props.values.map(result => (
        {
            id: result.name,
            text: result.name
        }));
this.state = {
        tags: tags,
        suggestions: props.suggestions ? props.suggestions.map(result => ({
            id: result.name,
            text: result.name
        })) : []
    };

}
```

You can make one different method getDerivedStateFromProps that gives you the new props coming and the prevState stored of your component. You may see in this if you want to assign your state to the changed props. This function returns the updated state. Below is the demo usecase where you can compare that the props coming in and the state containing your props are different, than you may assign props to state.

```
 static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
        if (nextProps.suggestions!== prevState.suggestions) {
            return {
                suggestions: nextProps.suggestions ? nextProps.suggestions.map(result => ({
            id: result.name,
            text: result.name
        })) : []
            };
        }
        return null;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks but this isn't working.  As the "suggestions" parameter (prop) changes as it is passed into the component, the component is not accurately reflecting its new values.

Comment: Ideally you should not mutate props into the component, its not good practice, but if the case is like props are changing due to parent, then you may use getDerivedStateFromProps which I have mentioned in my answer. This method takes in the props passed and their you can assign those props to your state. You may explore the link I have shared for getDerivedSateFromProps

Comment: So in your answer would I just make "this.state = getDerivedStateFromProps(..."?  Also I want to do things the "right" way, so what is the most common use case for something like this -- a child component changing in response to new data loaded in the parent?

Comment: I have shared the function that you can write for getDerivedStateFromProps. As a normal practice, considering your useCase, you can assign your props to state of component, and use getDerivedStateFromProps to update your state, in case the props changes. Also you can also consider using props directly, even without assigning to state i.e. use `this.props.suggestions`  directly into render. Hope this answer your queries. You may upvote or accept if you find the answer useful. Thanks :)